# how to edit this rules of iptables to cover all ports?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

i have this rules of iptables to limit connection per ip and i need to edit this rules to cover all **tcp/udp ports**

```
sudo iptables -N tcpsyn
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j tcpsyn
sudo iptables -A tcpsyn -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 5/second --limit-burst 40 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A tcpsyn -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 \
         -m connlimit --connlimit-above 40 --connlimit-mask 40 -j DROP
```

Comment: This rules cover all ip when do `tcpsyn` on port `80`. What you wish to do? Limit `tcpsun` to all port's or?

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i need to cover all udp/tcp ports not only port 80 tcp

Comment: Hopefully this can help you out: http://serverfault.com/questions/508700/reduce-firewall-rules-by-half-one-iptables-rule-for-tcp-and-udp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple remove `--dport` from command

Example

```
sudo iptables -D tcpsyn -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 5/second --limit-burst 40 -j RETURN
```

then add rules

```
sudo iptables -N tcpsyn
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j tcpsyn
sudo iptables -A tcpsyn -p tcp -m limit --limit 5/second --limit-burst 40 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A tcpsyn -p tcp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -m connlimit --connlimit-above 40 --connlimit-mask 40 -j DROP
```

`UDP` do not have `tcpsyn` Simple add number of simultaneous connection. You can create new chain

```
sudo iptables -N udp
```

then add rules to chain

```
sudo iptables -A udp -p udp -m limit --limit 5/second --limit-burst 40 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A udp -p udp -j DROP
```

Should be work.

EDIT 1

Rule to allow specific ip

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT
```

Rule to allow specific ip to access to specific port

```
iptables -A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 33332 -j ACCEPT
```

Rule to allow access to specific port

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 33332 -j ACCEPT
```

One rule for more ports

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

`-A` mean append or add like last rule. IPtables go from top to the end and stop on first rule match. You can use `iptables -I INPUT XX` `XX` is number to place rule in chain.

Comment: thanks for solution, can i make Exception for my ip ?

Comment: Yes. `iptables -I INPUT 1 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT`. This will put rule on first place in INPUT chain. `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` replace with you ip.

Comment: last question  Exception port? hhhh :p i am sorry for noising you

Comment: *forget to mention you

Comment: I add some rules in my answer. See EDIT 1